# cast("decimal(32,9)") is converting into scientific value 0E-9 for the input value 0

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am using a very basic spark code in order to convert the input value "Qty" into an output variable that will be inserted into a RDBMS however for the input value "0", spark cast("decimal(32,9)") is converting it into 0E-9.
Here is my code:

```
dfFinal = dfInput.withColumn("QtyOut",dfInput.col("Qty").cast("decimal(32,9)");
dfFinal.show();
```

When the value of Qty is "0" the output is given as "0E-9". Then i tried using "format_number" which solves the problem but then converts QtyOut to string and adds "," for numbers greater than 999.
Here is the code for that

```
dfFinal = dfInput.withColumn("NewQtyOut",format_number(dfInput.col("curr_notl_amt"),9));
```

Comment: It's odd that this `show()` method displays it that way, but there's no difference in value between `0` and `0e-9` or any other exponent. Also, `show()` is certainly also converting it to string, just not in a nice way.

Comment: As david said, both are same, done a check for you. If it helps please accept and upvote

Answer (score 0):

Both `0` and `0E-9` are same, hence I don't know why you are trying to convert it to `0.000000000`.

Here is the test of that-

```scala
   val dfInput = spark.range(1).withColumn("Qty", col("id").cast(StringType))
    val processDF = dfInput.withColumn("QtyOut",dfInput.col("Qty").cast("decimal(32,9)"))
    processDF.show(false)
    processDF.printSchema()

    processDF.withColumn("NewQtyOut",format_number(processDF.col("QtyOut"),9)).show()
    processDF.withColumn("NewQtyOut",format_number(processDF.col("QtyOut"),9)).printSchema()

    processDF
      .withColumn("isTrue", when(col("QtyOut").equalTo(0), true).otherwise(false))
      .show(false)
```

Output-

```
+---+---+------+
|id |Qty|QtyOut|
+---+---+------+
|0  |0  |0E-9  |
+---+---+------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- Qty: string (nullable = false)
 |-- QtyOut: decimal(32,9) (nullable = true)

+---+---+------+-----------+
| id|Qty|QtyOut|  NewQtyOut|
+---+---+------+-----------+
|  0|  0|  0E-9|0.000000000|
+---+---+------+-----------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- Qty: string (nullable = false)
 |-- QtyOut: decimal(32,9) (nullable = true)
 |-- NewQtyOut: string (nullable = true)

+---+---+------+------+
|id |Qty|QtyOut|isTrue|
+---+---+------+------+
|0  |0  |0E-9  |true  |
+---+---+------+------+
```

Please observe `isTrue` column.

### Edit-1 (based on comments)

Convert the `decimal` from scientific notation by with the `scale` we want-

```scala
 def bigDecimalFormatter(x: Double, y: Int): Double =
      BigDecimal(x).setScale(y, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble

    val decimalFormatter = udf((decimal: Double, scale: Int) => bigDecimalFormatter(decimal, scale))
    processDF.select(decimalFormatter(col("QtyOut"), lit(9)),
      decimalFormatter(lit(1.1000000453E4), lit(5)))
      .show(false)
```

Output-

```
+--------------+--------------------+
|UDF(QtyOut, 9)|UDF(11000.000453, 5)|
+--------------+--------------------+
|0.0           |11000.00045         |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Though both are same, this is the case with only 0. If i have value of Qty as 1, it will print 1.00000..(till the scale defined). My data gets inserted into database, and hence the value 0 is getting inserted as 0E-9 which is causing error.